# Is it possible to place an element that takes up the full viewport over a canvas without blocking the canvas's ability to interact with the pointer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to overlay a `section` element that takes up the entire viewport on top of a `canvas` element. The `canvas` element is displaying webgl that interacts with the mouse location through javascript. Unfortunately, the `section` element is blocking the javascript from recognizing the mouse location because it doesn't come in contact with the canvas.

**Attempted the following solutions:** I added `pointer-events: none;` to the `section` and `h1` elements, but it didn't help.

It is important that the `section` element take up the entire viewport because I intend to add css animations and a graphic inside of it later that must be centered using flexbox.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible and if so, how can I achieve this?

```js
window['webgl-fluid'].default(document.querySelector('canvas'))
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

section {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100vw;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <section>
    <h1>WebGL Fluid Simulation</h1>
  </section>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.9/dat.gui.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/webgl-fluid@0.0.4/dist/webgl-fluid.umd.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you are saying the pointer-events none is not doing that?

Comment: Using pointer-events: none does not allow the pointer interactions to pass through the section so that the canvas can recognize the pointer location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set position absolute on the section the mouse events are not captured.

```js
window['webgl-fluid'].default(document.querySelector('canvas'))
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

section {
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100vw;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <section>
    <h1>WebGL Fluid Simulation</h1>
  </section>
  <canvas></canvas>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.7.9/dat.gui.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/webgl-fluid@0.0.4/dist/webgl-fluid.umd.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```